# bash looping and extracting of the fragment of txt file

Tags: bash, loops, logging, awk, sed

I am dealing with the analysis of big number of dlg text files located within the workdir. Each file has a table (usually located in different positions of the log) in the following format:

File 1:

```
    CLUSTERING HISTOGRAM
    ____________________


________________________________________________________________________________
     |           |     |           |     |
Clus | Lowest    | Run | Mean      | Num | Histogram
-ter | Binding   |     | Binding   | in  |
Rank | Energy    |     | Energy    | Clus|    5    10   15   20   25   30   35
_____|___________|_____|___________|_____|____:____|____:____|____:____|____:___
   1 |     -5.78 |  11 |     -5.78 |   1 |#
   2 |     -5.53 |  13 |     -5.53 |   1 |#
   3 |     -5.47 |  17 |     -5.44 |   2 |##
   4 |     -5.43 |  20 |     -5.43 |   1 |#
   5 |     -5.26 |  19 |     -5.26 |   1 |#
   6 |     -5.24 |   3 |     -5.24 |   1 |#
   7 |     -5.19 |   4 |     -5.19 |   1 |#
   8 |     -5.14 |  16 |     -5.14 |   1 |#
   9 |     -5.11 |   9 |     -5.11 |   1 |#
  10 |     -5.07 |   1 |     -5.07 |   1 |#
  11 |     -5.05 |  14 |     -5.05 |   1 |#
  12 |     -4.99 |  12 |     -4.99 |   1 |#
  13 |     -4.95 |   8 |     -4.95 |   1 |#
  14 |     -4.93 |   2 |     -4.93 |   1 |#
  15 |     -4.90 |  10 |     -4.90 |   1 |#
  16 |     -4.83 |  15 |     -4.83 |   1 |#
  17 |     -4.82 |   6 |     -4.82 |   1 |#
  18 |     -4.43 |   5 |     -4.43 |   1 |#
  19 |     -4.26 |   7 |     -4.26 |   1 |#
_____|___________|_____|___________|_____|______________________________________
```

The aim is to loop over all the dlg files and take the single line from the table corresponding to wider cluster (with bigger number of slashes in Histogram column). In the above example from the table this is the third line.

```
   3 |     -5.47 |  17 |     -5.44 |   2 |##
```

Then I need to add this line to the final_log.txt together with the name of the log file (that should be specified before the line). So in the end I should have something in following format (for 3 different log files):

```
"Name of the file 1": 3 |     -5.47 |  17 |     -5.44 |   2 |##
"Name_of_the_file_2": 1 |     -5.99 |  13 |     -5.98 |  16 |################
"Name_of_the_file_3": 2 |     -4.78 |  19 |     -4.44 |   3 |###
```

A possible model of my BASH workflow would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
do
  file_name2=$(basename "$f")
  file_name="${file_name2/.dlg}"
  echo "Processing of $f..."
  # take a name of the file and save it in the log
  echo "$file_name" >> $PWD/final_results.log
  # search of the beginning of the table inside of each file and save it after its name
  cat $f |grep 'CLUSTERING HISTOGRAM' >> $PWD/final_results.log
  # check whether it works
  gedit $PWD/final_results.log
done
```

Here I need to substitute combination of echo and grep in order to take selected parts of the table.

Comment: Which line(s) should be collected in case of a tie?

Comment: Do you mean the example is embedded inside a larger file? Can there be more than one of these fragments in an input file? How can we distinguish these lines from lines which should be ignored?

Comment: right! the ranking table located somewhere in the log file so the line number may be different ;-) there is only one table in the following format. For the simplicity we can try to work on the example workflow taking the first line from the table for instance ;-))

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please don't move the goal posts after you have received multiple answers to your original question. If you still can't sort out the problem, (probably accept one of the answers you got here, and) post a new question with actual, representative data and a [mre].

Comment: This is apparently now the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140486/bash-extracting-the-first-line-from-the-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one, expected to be fast enough. Extra lines in your files, besides the tables, are not expected to be a problem.

```
grep "#$" *.dlg | sort -rk11 | awk '!seen[$1]++'
```

`grep` fetches all the histogram lines which are then sorted in reverse order by last field, that means lines with most `#` on the top, and finally `awk` removes the duplicates. Note that when `grep` is parsing more than one file, it has `-H` by default to print the filenames at the beginning of the line, so if you test it for one file, use `grep -H`.

Result should be like this:

```
file1.dlg:   3 |     -5.47 |  17 |     -5.44 |   2 |##########
file2.dlg:   3 |     -5.47 |  17 |     -5.44 |   2 |####
file3.dlg:   3 |     -5.47 |  17 |     -5.44 |   2 |#######
```

---

Here is a modification to get the first appearence in case of many equal max lines in a file:

```
grep "#$" *.dlg | sort -k11 | tac | awk '!seen[$1]++'
```

We replaced the reversed parameter in sort, with the 'tac' command which is reversing the file stream, so now for any equal lines, initial order is preserved.

---

**Second solution**

Here using only awk:

```
awk -F"|" '/#$/ && $NF > max[FILENAME] {max[FILENAME]=$NF; row[FILENAME]=$0}
           END {for (i in row) print i ":" row[i]}' *.dlg
```

---

Update: if you execute it from different directory and want to keep only the basename of every file, to remove the path prefix:

```
awk -F"|" '/#$/ && $NF > max[FILENAME] {max[FILENAME]=$NF; row[FILENAME]=$0}
           END {for (i in row) {sub(".*/","",i); print i ":" row[i]}}'
```

Comment: Generally, your sollution is quite simple and it gives actually very good results! What I've noticed: if I use grep (without -H):  it gives SEVERAL lines (of the table) from each of the file sorted according to number of #... If I use Grep -H: it gives what I need BUT at the first place it gives not a name of the file but rather its full path where it is located... so.. :-)

Comment: Sorry I did not understand completely the last point. Does it nessesary to CD each time within the DIR to avoid full path in the resulting log ? Actually I just put your one line solluting inside of my loop and it functionally it works very well: I am going to edit my first topic how it works in my case .. Thank you again.

Comment: You can easily add a simple `sub` to the Awk script to trim off the beginning of the file name if that's more convenient, at the expense of making the script slightly less elegant.  Hint: `sub(/.*\//, "", $1)` removes everything up until the last slash in `$1`.

Comment: also I've just noticed a small issue with your sollution (which is very very good in any case!!). Actually In the case if in the table there are several lines with the SAME number of # , the script will take the BOTTOM line with equal #. Would it be possible to take rather the FIRST occurence of the line with biggest number of # in the last column ? To be clear, imagine that in the table (from the first post) there are all 10 lines with #, in that case I need to take the line number 1. :-)

Comment: The `sort` will effectively scramble the order of the output lines, so Awk can't know what their order was in the input (and thus doesn't particularly favor the first or the last); but you can probably stabiliee it by adding secondary sort keys; maybe `sort -k11:11r,1:1,2:2n`

Comment: thank you very much again for your kind help! I did not understand here the technical details BUT your second sollution works very well for my particular case: it correctly identify the table than it takes either a string with the highest number of # or alternatively in the case of simular number of # it takes it first occurence within the table. I've just tested it on 7000 filles and it seems to me that it perfectly does the job ! thank you again

Comment: just one question: how would it be possible to modify the second sollution in order to simplify the format of the resulting line. Now I have it (for each file) in the following format : /scratch_p/jonnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_101.dlg:   6 |     -4.37 |   3 |     -4.36 |   5 |#####              What I need just to show in the begining the name of the file (without it full path): 7000_01_lig_cne_101.dlg:

Comment: hey, I just like to use loops :-))) one more question about the SECOND SOLUTION proposed in this answer. Is it possible to set up some FILTER to exclude all lines  in  with the number of # (in last columnt) less than 5 ? (e.g. for #, ##, ###, ####) ? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably makes more sense as an Awk script.

This picks the first line with the widest histogram in the case of a tie within an input file.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'FNR == 1 { if(sel) print sel; sel = ""; max = 0 }
   FNR < 9 { next }
   length($10) > max { max = length($10); sel = FILENAME ":" $0 }
   END { if (sel) print sel }' ./"$prot"/*.dlg
```

This assumes the histograms are always the tenth field; if your input format is even messier than the lump you show, maybe adapt to taste.

In some more detail, the first line triggers on the first line of each input file. If we have collected a previous line (meaning this is not the first input file), print that, and start over. Otherwise, initialize for the first input file.  Set `sel` to nothing and `max` to zero.

The second line skips lines 1-8 which contain the header.

The third line checks if the current line's histogram is longer than `max`. If it is, update `max` to this histogram's length, and remember the current line in `sel`.

The last line is spillover for when we have processed all files. We never printed the `sel` from the last file, so print that too, if it's set.

If you mean to say we should find the lines between `CLUSTERING HISTOGRAM` and the end of the table, we should probably have more information about what the surrounding lines look like. Maybe something like this, though;

```sh
awk '/CLUSTERING HISTOGRAM/ { if (sel) print sel; looking = 1; sel = ""; max = 0 }
   !looking { next }
   looking > 1 && $1 != looking { looking = 0; nextfile }
   $1 == looking && length($10) > max { max = length($10); sel = FILENAME ":" $0 }
   END { if (sel) print sel }' ./"$prot"/*.dlg
```

This sets `looking` to 1 when we see `CLUSTERING HISTOGRAM`, then counts up to the first line where `looking` is no longer increasing.

Comment: it saves something to my final log but not the proper line. I suppose I need combination of SED and AWK to find the table in the *.dlg file by SED (usually the table in the RANDOM places within the file) and then to save only only line from it :- )

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say, but you generally don't need to combine `sed` with Awk. If you want to substitute something, use Awk's `gsub` function.

Comment: Oh, and you need to skip the header. Is it always the same length? Added a quick workaround

Comment: sorry for misunderstandings! yes the table always present in the following format but indeed it could be within the log file in slightly different places! and I need only one line from the table, more specificly the negative number that occurs in the second column ;-)

Comment: This is all rather messy. Perhaps accept one of the answers here (or post one of your own and accept that) and ask a new question with the actual requirements spelled out properly, with a representative sample of something you cannot currently handle with the tools you have.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest processing using **awk**:

```
for i in $FILES
do
    echo -n \""$i\": "
    awk 'BEGIN {
           output="";
           outputlength=0
         }
         /(^ *[0-9]+)/ {                                    # process only lines that start with a number
           if (length(substr($10, 2)) > outputlength) {     # if line has more hashes, store it
             output=$0;
             outputlength=length(substr($10, 2))
           }
         }
         END {
           print output                                     # output the resulting line
         }' "$i"
done
```

Comment: it does not select the proper fragment. could you give me an example of AWK for my loop which will just find in each of *.dlg file for the "keyword" and than copy it to the final_result.log file ? thanks !!