# bash extracting the first line from the table

Tags: bash, grep

A second question for threatment of log files for table-patterns. I am dealing with the analysis of big number of dlg text files located within the workdir. Each file has a table (usually located in the end of the log) in the following format:

```
 RMSD TABLE
    __________


_____________________________________________________________________
     |      |      |           |         |                 |
Rank | Sub- | Run  | Binding   | Cluster | Reference       | Grep
     | Rank |      | Energy    | RMSD    | RMSD            | Pattern
_____|______|______|___________|_________|_________________|___________
   1      1      7       -1.43      0.00    178.12           RANKING
   1      2     18       -0.96      1.88    177.35           RANKING
   2      1      4       -0.97      0.00    178.43           RANKING
   3      1     13       -0.60      0.00    178.03           RANKING
   4      1      5       -0.56      0.00    198.10           RANKING
   5      1     16       +0.01      0.00    189.71           RANKING
   6      1      3       +0.06      0.00    176.95           RANKING
   7      1     19       +0.10      0.00    177.27           RANKING
   8      1     17       +0.13      0.00    177.60           RANKING
   9      1      8       +0.20      0.00    177.05           RANKING
  10      1     20       +0.27      0.00    177.43           RANKING
  11      1     10       +0.34      0.00    176.33           RANKING
  12      1      6       +0.37      0.00    177.30           RANKING
  13      1      9       +0.44      0.00    175.48           RANKING
  14      1      2       +0.46      0.00    175.67           RANKING
  15      1     11       +0.84      0.00    177.52           RANKING
  15      2     12       +1.31      1.95    178.03           RANKING
  16      1     14       +1.29      0.00    201.01           RANKING
  17      1     15       +1.65      0.00    175.50           RANKING
  18      1      1       +1.96      0.00    186.83           RANKING

Run time 3.909 sec
Idle time 0.817 sec
```

The aim is to loop over all the .dlg files and take the single line from the table corresponding to its first line (ignorring the header) ommiting the last column (normally provided for grep recognition). In the above example from the table this is the third line.

```
      1      1      7       -1.43      0.00    178.12
```

Then I need to add this line to the final_log.txt together with the name of the log file (that should be specified before).
Based on my very recent experience a possible model for my BASH workflow (for threatment of several files) may be:

```
#!/bin/bash
#name of the folder containing all *.dlg filles to be analysed
prot='7000'
#path to the folder with these *.dlg filles
FILES=$PWD/${prot}/*.dlg
#make a final log
echo 'This is a list of processed filles' > $PWD/final_results.log
# we loop over all *.dlg filles in order to extract Clustering Histogram to the final LOG file
for f in $FILES
do
  file_name2=$(basename "$f")
  file_name="${file_name2/.dlg}"
  echo "Processing of $f..."
  # here is an expression for GREP to take the line from the table and save it to >> $PWD/final_results.log
done
```

Comment: This is apparently a follow-up question (with slightly different input) after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123229/bash-looping-and-extracting-of-the-fragment-of-txt-file

Comment: If there are unrelated lines earlier in the input file, can we assume none of the start wit a digit, and/or none of them end with `RANKING`? Either way, probably be more explicit if this is an important requirement.

Comment: `"${file_name2/.dlg}"` looks like a typo, do you mean `"${file_name2%.dlg}"` to trim off the extension, perhaps? Generalny speaking, code which doesn't do what you want is a terrible way to explain what you do want.

Comment: hello, yes exactly it is quite similar question to what I have already asked, for the same type of input data (txt files with logs). Sorry for the typo, yes actually I used this command to trip the extension of the file (If it is nessesary). Briefly I am looking for a simple one line command that could be introduced in the loop (which handle the filles in the workdir) to look into the DLG text file and extract the first line from the another table (usually occured at the end of the log)...

Comment: If you refuse to answer requests for clarifications, you risk getting downvoted and/or having your question closed. Is vgersh99's answer suitable or do you have hidden requirements which prevent it from working? Properly speaking you should _again_ accept the answer to the question you actually asked, and then post a new question if you now have different requirements.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you are spending people's patience quickly here.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/ZkeQJz for what some actual test data might look like. I'm going to vote to close this as duplicate / unclear; please feel free to ask a new question once you have a better grasp of [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

how about to start with - assuming gawk with the `nextfile` support:

```sh
gawk '$1~/[[:digit:]]/{ print FILENAME, substr($0,1,match($0,/[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+$/)-1);nextfile}' *.dlg
```

Comment: This assumes the first line which starts with a digit is the one we seek. Can we assume there are no lines with this feature earlier in the file?

Comment: hey I like your elegant sollution with the exeption that it rather takes the line from the another table, which occures just before the second one (mentioned in my first topic) :-)) sorry i forgot to mention that in the DLG file there are two tables in similar format and I ought to operate with the second one (which is usually at the end of the file ). Cheers