# shell: treatment of the multi-line format according to its column patterns

Tags: csv, awk

Dealing with multi-line CSV file, I am looking for a possible Bash shell workflow that could be useful for its treatment. Here is format of the file containing data in multi-column format:

```
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_1000.dlg:   6 |     -4.86 |   2 |     -4.79 |   4 |####
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_1001.dlg:   2 |     -5.25 |  10 |     -5.22 |   8 |########
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_1002.dlg:   5 |     -5.76 |   6 |     -5.48 |   3 |###
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_1003.dlg:   4 |     -3.88 |  17 |     -3.50 |   3 |###
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_1009.dlg:   5 |     -4.51 |   5 |     -4.39 |   4 |####
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_100.dlg:   3 |     -4.40 |  11 |     -4.38 |   9 |#########
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_1010.dlg:   1 |     -5.07 |  15 |     -4.51 |   5 |#####
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_150.dlg:   4 |     -5.01 |   5 |     -4.82 |   3 |###
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_156.dlg:   2 |     -5.38 |  11 |     -4.70 |   3 |###
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_157.dlg:   1 |     -4.22 |  10 |     -4.16 |   7 |#######
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_167.dlg:   2 |     -3.85 |   3 |     -3.69 |   9 |#########
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_168.dlg:   2 |     -4.42 |  12 |     -4.01 |   6 |######
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_169.dlg:   2 |     -4.94 |  17 |     -4.80 |   5 |#####
/scratch_p/johnycash/results_test_docking/7000/7000_01_lig_cne_16.dlg:   1 |     -6.23 |   4 |     -5.77 |   4 |###
```

According to the format: all the columns with valuable information are divided by `|` with the exception of the first column (name of the line), divided by `:` from the rest. The script should operate with following post-processing:

1. Descending sorting of all lines according to the value from the third column (from mostly negative to positive values);
2. Set up some filter to the last column (according to the number of `#`), discarding all of the lines containing `#`, `##` or `###`. Alternatively this filter can be applied on the penultimate column, which expresses the number of `#`characters as a number.

While I can do the first task using sort

```
sort -t '|' -k 3 filename.csv
```

and the second may be achieved using AWK

```
awk '(NR>1) && ($8 > 2) ' filename.csv > filename_processed.txt
```

how could I combine the both commands in efficient fashion taking into account the format of my file?

Comment: Thanks for posting your efforts in form of code, could you please post expected output too in your question and let us know then.

Comment: hello, actually I have already tried to do it, while performing all of the described things manually in libre-calc BUT output file had no the same format as the initial in terms of separators ... this is why I am looking for SHELL sollution to keep the both filles in the same format

Comment: it this related? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123229/bash-looping-and-extracting-of-the-fragment-of-txt-file ... (I would expect that you had kept the basename only at first field also)

Comment: `descending sorting` means downwards while `from mostly negative to positive values` means upwards.

Comment: what is the 3rd field? with or without the filename? the one with only negative values or the next with only positive ones. Also include the exact expected output for this input.

Comment: I reduced the humongous sample to a smaller set but might have removed something useful; the old version is still visible in the revision history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested in shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
gsub(/#/,"&",$6)>4
' Input_file | sort -t'|' -nk 3 > output_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment to get last 10% lines from starting of Input_file you could following, take above command's output into a output file and could run following.

```
awk -v lines="$(wc -l < output_file)" '
BEGIN{
  tenPer=int(lines/10)
}
FNR>(tenPer){exit}
1
' output_file
```

***For getting 10% last lines of output_file try:***

```
tac output_file | 
awk -v lines="$(wc -l < output_file)" 'BEGIN{tenPer=int(lines/10)} FNR>tenPer{exit} 1' | 
tac
```

***OR***

```
awk -v lines="$(wc -l < output_file)" 'BEGIN{tenPer=int(lines/10)} FNR>=(lines-tenPer)' output_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
sort -nr -k 4 scratch.scv | grep -v -E "[^#]#{1,3}$"
```

Sort base on column value and eject the line with 1-3 number of #.

Comment: thank you very much! it does the job preaty well, with the exeption that its sorts the values from positive to negative (I need reverse ). Actually this propositions works quite well for me :  grep -E "#{4}$" file | sort -t"|" -nk2

Answer (score 3):

It is better to sort at the end with fewer lines.

```
grep -E "#{4}$" file | sort -t"|" -nk3
```

If you need to filter for different number of `#` modify the number in the expression of `grep`. If you need reversed sorting add the `r` parameter to the `sort` command. If you need sorting per different column, modify the `k` argument.

Comment: awesome, thank you so much! it acually does it, I've just modified sorting function to recognize properly the column that I have to sort (the bug might be due to different types of separator in the table): | sort -t"|" -nk2      Could you tell me, is it possible to pipe your sollution to some command which will take at the end only the 10% of the lines (from the bottom) from the output file after it processing by your script ? Thanks again !!

Comment: Thank you anyway Dude! We have just found a sollution using AWK to take the 10% of the sorted log, kindly proposed before. So now we do have both sollutions, but anyway yours is very eligant I shall keep it !

Comment: hey dude,  actually I've tried to accept the both sollutions since I like them equally but the system did not allow to do it so I rose the reputations for them ..

Answer (score 1):

If your commands are really all you need, trivially

```sh
awk '(NR>1) && ($8 > 2) ' filename.csv |
sort -t '|' -k 3 filename.csv > filename_processed.txt
```

Comment: Please don't call me dude. I just took the commands which you say worked in isolation; if they don't, probably modify accordingly. I was vaguely surprised you used `$8 > 2` when your requirements say 3 or more.